# How to check if a category has been selected for a product while adding it in magento?

Tags: magento

I need to check if a category has been selected for a product while I add product in admin panel in magento.
Client need to enable some product tab for specific category and for other it will be disabled.

If client select a particular category then the tab will be active otherwise it will not.

Please help me with the situation.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript to check whether that category (each checkbox should have a unique ID) is checked, and if it is you can enable/disable tab.